# Implementing a generic real time collaborative editor/plugin (Like Google Docs)

Tags: javascript, html, collaborative-editing

So, I'm looking at implementing a real time collaborative editor, as some of the pre made ones (such as [etherpad](http://beta.etherpad.org/)) lack the features of a dedicated editor.

I currently use [CKEditor](http://ckeditor.com/), but am looking to switch to [Aloha Editor](http://aloha-editor.org/).

I am going to be using [Pusher](http://pusher.com/) for push notifications / update to places around my app so that everything can be as real time as possible as multiple people use the software.

Now, initially my thought process on how to implement a collaborative editor seems really slow -- To constantly swap out entire text fields using pusher... but moving giant blocks of text around would get terribly ugly fast, and I'm not really sure what to do when there are multiple ( > 5 ) people working on text at the same time.. So... there MUST be an easier, more network efficient way to go about doing collaborative editing.

Ideas?

Comment: not a whole lot on implementation (I haven't really found any details). just existing editors.

Comment: Maybe do some background research, then you can ask a slightly more specific question than "How do I do it"?

Comment: well, judging by the answer by @Sergio Tulentsev, I think I'd need to write a plugin for CKEditor or Aloha that is intregrated with Pusher for smart deltas...  And calculate the offset at certain locations for each editor until an update is made.

Comment: Yes, it's a very hard problem, so you'll want to use an existing library / service. 
 Here's an article we put together discussing the various generic (meaning not tied to any specific UI component) solutions: https://convergencelabs.com/realtime-collaboration-technology-guide/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A real time collaboration plugin for the Aloha-Editor called Aloha-Wikdiocs was released at the jQuery conference 2012. It's still alpha but already works quite well.

It's not open source. The real-time collaboration is provided as a service that can be integrated with existing systems. Currently there is no fee for this service.

There is a demo and some documentation on how to integrate the service on the [website](http://api.wikidocs.com).

Comment: you are my new best friend o.o

Comment: @TheLindyHop, Hmm, did you get an API Key and replace the corresponding values in the sample code? I got the example working for me: http://github.com/Aloha-Wikidocs/Example

Comment: @TheLindyHop, I have it working in Google Chrome 16.0.912.77. What version are you using? Are there any errors in the console?

Comment: no errors, just nothing happens when I try to connect to facebook.

Comment: and I have version 17. something (latest stable, I think(also not the dev version -- that one breaks a lot))

Comment: Try to clone the github example. There is no Facebook involved and it should work out of the box. The only thing to do is to touch a file with the API key. https://github.com/Aloha-Wikidocs/Example

Comment: @TheLindyHop, when you click the "connect" button, does a popup open? If yes, does logging in with facebook make the red box with the "connect" button vanish?

Comment: nope, no popup. There is something wrong with my chrome though, as the downloads bar doesn't even show up when I download stuff. o.o idk. Not sure if problem with my chrome or what.

Answer (score 1):

Group changes together and calculate smart deltas.

For example, a user presses keys 'h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o'. Your javascript groups them and reports to the server: "User A inserted text 'hello' at position X".

You get the idea.

Comment: yup. lots of math involved in this approach. WHEEEEE! =D

Comment: @TheLindyHop: it's exciting, isn't it? :-)

Comment: do you happen to know of some collaborative engine that can be plugged into different editors with some work? I mean, no reason to re-invent teh wheel if I don't have to.

Comment: @TheLindyHop: I'm all for not reinventing the wheel, but I don't know such technologies. As a user, I am amazed by google docs :-)

Comment: Here are some resources for that https://convergencelabs.com/realtime-collaboration-technology-guide/